# aspnet_regsql error not connecting to server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-membership

I have a asp.net application that I am trying to get to connect to a database and store users login details.

I changed the regsql programme to my database it creates the tables but when I go into asp.net configuration site it still connecting to a local database how do I go about changing this.

I assuming that it is something to do with the web.config file.

Comment: This is since i have moved my website from local server to a web server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're using the default membership provider using the default connection string. You need to make sure it's using the new connection string to the database you want to use. This means either removing then adding the connectionstring it uses with your new connectionstring or setting up a new membership provider to use your new connectionstring.

Comment: Thanks i now get this error
Could not establish a connection to the database. 
If you have not yet created the SQL Server database, exit the Web Site Administration tool, use the aspnet_regsql command-line utility to create and configure the database, and then return to this tool to set the provider.